# Azure Java functions TimerTrigger to fire on startup

Tags: azure-functions, azure-java-tools

Azure functions with `C#` provides a way to run the `TimerTrigger` at starts up time with `RunOnStartup` parameter as follows.

```
[FunctionName("TimeTrigger_Startup")]
public async Task Migrations([TimerTrigger("0 */4 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger logger) {
     // Startup script
}
```

But, there is no option for `Java TimerTrigger` functions.

```
@FunctionName("Warmup")
public void run(@TimerTrigger(name = "warmupTrigger", schedule = "0 */4 * * * *") String timerInfo, ExecutionContext context) {
   // Startup script
}
```

There is no equivalent variable for `RunOnStartup` in annotation `@TimerTrigger` to start at start time. Is there any work around to execute the method in Azure Java function on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this not possible using annotations. Current work-around is to add these properties in the generated  `function.json` file as [described here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-library/issues/147). There is an [open PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-library/pull/154) which will address this issue.